# Payment Declined in A Play Console inAppPurchase

Tags: java, android

Integreted inAppPurchase Most of Orders display That Payment Declined 
only 1 succesfull purchase out of 7 or more order 
most of orders goes Payment declined

seee image atteched here[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwFit.png)

Answer (score 0):

First, this does not belong to stackoverflow because its not a programming question.

To answer your question, not all purchases are successful. The user's payment could be declined for various reasons and you can do nothing about it